# Encode Private Key getting Error: asn1: structure error: tags don't match

Tags: go, x509, pkcs#11

When i try to parses the encode private key with

sample private key

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
 x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
```

it will giving me error 
Explain:

```
case "OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY":
        log.Println("Here at OPENSSH Private Key:")
        rsa, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
        log.Println("Rsa and Error:", rsa, err)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        rawkey = rsa
```

key

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
key
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Getting Error:

```
asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:1 tag:15 length:112 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} pkcs1PrivateKey @2
2019/04/02 13:57:52 Signer: <nil>
```

and I will also try with

```
 x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
```

But same Error getting.

Comment: Could you post the header of your private key?

Comment: -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Try using [ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseRawPrivateKey) from `x/crypto`.

Comment: I try but getting ssh: no key found

Comment: Is it passphrase protected? If so, you may need to use [ssh.ParseRawPrivateKeyWithPassphrase](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseRawPrivateKeyWithPassphrase)

Comment: No it's not passphrase protected.

Comment: At this point, we can't help. Please post reproducible code, including the input. You can generate a new throwaway key and use that in your example. Then we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @Marc I'll try with the new key if not working I'll post the code and the sample private key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191096/discussion-between-black-dreams-and-marc).

Comment: @Marc I add the code and the sample key below please see where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is the key type. `OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` should be parsed with `ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey`, whereas `RSA PRIVATE KEY` can be parsed with both `ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey` and `x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey`.

You can generate `RSA PRIVATE KEY` with e.g. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f key.pem -m pem` (**-m pem** here is important) or `openssl genrsa -out key.pem`, and test it with `openssl rsa -check -in key.pem`.

So just do a block type check and use the corresponding functions in the case clauses to parse the key.

Also think about key encryption, which means you might need to use `ssh.ParseRawPrivateKeyWithPassphrase` or `x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock` and `x509.DecryptPEMBlock` functions too.

Answer (score -1):

I post the test private key and the code which I used

Sample private key:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Signed the constructed json string with business private key

```
func SignatureWithPrivateKey(data string) string {
    signer, err := loadPrivateKey("/Users/sumitthakur/test")
    log.Println("Signer:", signer)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("signer is damaged: %v", err)
    }

    toSign := data

    signed, err := signer.Sign([]byte(toSign))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("could not sign request: %v", err)
    }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signed)

}
```

loadPrivateKey loads an parses a PEM encoded private key file.

```
func loadPrivateKey(path string) (Signer, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Println("Data and Error pem:", data, err)
    return parsePrivateKey(data)
}
```

parses an encoded private key.

```
func parsePrivateKey(pemBytes []byte) (Signer, error) {
    block, err := pem.Decode(pemBytes)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("ssh: no key found")
    }

    log.Println("Block and Error: ", block, err)

    var rawkey interface{}
    switch block.Type {
    case "OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY":
        log.Println("Here at OPENSSH Private Key:")
        rsa, err := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(block.Bytes)
        log.Println("Rsa and Error:", rsa, err)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        rawkey = rsa
    default:
        log.Println("Here at default")
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ssh: unsupported key type %q", block.Type)
    }
    return newSignerFromKey(rawkey)
}
```

Comment: Please edit your original question, don't create an answer. Also `ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey` takes the raw pem-encoded bytes, you shouldn't call `pem.Decode`.

Comment: ok I try with remove the pem.decode but it wouldn't give me the result !!! say's no key found.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but this works: https://play.golang.org/p/VWs_VNzhGcK and returns a `rsa.PrivateKey`

Comment: I had an issue when I pasted pem content on string and my editor add tab. This made ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey fails. I took me a while to realize tabulations